# Angularjs button click $mdDialog not working

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script src="angsc.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main ng-app="myModule">
        <div ui-view=""></div>
    <main>
       </body>
     </html>
```

This is my master page

```
<div ng-controller="myController">  
<input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addclick()">
<input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="searchclick()">
<br/>
</div>
```

This is my content page.

```
var myApp = angular
            .module("myModule",['$mdDialog'])
            .controller("myController",function ($mdDialog,$scope){
                $scope.addclick=function(){
                    $mdDialog.show({
                         template:'addnew.html'
                    }); 
                };
                $scope.searchclick=function(){
                    $mdDialog.show({
                         template:'searchold.html'
                    }); 
                };
            });
```

This is my js file.                                                                                                                                         
I also have 2 html files namely "addnew.html" and "searchold.html".  Not getting pop up of those two files on button click.  Is there an error in my code?  Kindly help me..

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for your question?

Comment: Also your closing body tag miss bracket

Comment: sorry I dont know creating 2 html page in fiddle..Yeah closed it. still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependent module name is wrong. Instead of `$mdDialog` it should be `ngMaterial`. `$mdDialog` is the service being injected in controller and is part of the `ngMaterial` module. Change your code as below to get it working:

```
var myApp = angular
        .module("myModule",['ngMaterial'])
        .controller("myController",function ($mdDialog,$scope){
            $scope.addclick=function(){
                $mdDialog.show({
                     template:'addnew.html'
                }); 
            };
            $scope.searchclick=function(){
                $mdDialog.show({
                     template:'searchold.html'
                }); 
            };
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      </script>    
  <script src="angsc.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <main ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">  
      <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addclick()">
      <input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="searchclick()">
      <br/>
    </div>
  <main>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/addi90/pen/ZOEqZq

Comment: What is the state configuration you are using? It seems then that there is an issue with the conflict between your state configuration and `ng-controller`. Please provide the code for state configuration to understand the issue better

Comment: You have used `ui-view` directive from `ui-router` which needs state configuration. Are you using the states for multiple routes/ views?

Comment: I dont think so.  I had completely put up the code in my question.

Comment: Ok. That is your issue. You should not use `ui-view` if you don't have state configuration defined. I have updated the html code in my answer and a working codepen for your issue

Comment: Hi I would like to ask how to load that addnew.html as popup instead of displaying it?

Comment: Use `templateUrl` instead of `template` and pas it the url of your template

Comment: My pleasure. Please upvote too if the answer worked for you :)